# Parallel For c#

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to improve the performance of a method that calculates the mean of an image.

For that I'm using two For statements to iterate all the image, therefore I tried to use a Parallel For to improve this, but the results are not the same.

Am I doing it wrong? or what is it causing the difference?

```
public static double MeanDN(this GrayImage image)
{
  double mean = 0;
  int totalPixels = image.Width * image.Height;

  for (int i = 0; i < image.Height; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < image.Width; j++)
          mean += (double)image[i, j] / totalPixels;

  double parallelMean = 0;

  Parallel.For(0, image.Height, i =>
  {
      for (int j = 0; j < image.Width; j++)
          parallelMean += (double)image[i, j] / totalPixels;
  });

  return mean;
}
```

**Output:**

> mean = 404.12
>
> parallelMean = 148.8658

Comment: synchronous? (3 more to go)

Comment: `Parallel.for` is asynchronous method.
`for` issynchronous method.

Comment: How can I improve the performance of this method? can it be done with Parallel for?

Comment: Is correct answer  404.12?

Comment: yes, the mean is correct, parallelmean is incorrect

Comment: The problem is that you don't sync access to parallelMean. Also you can improve performance by replacing the get on properties with local variables (var imageWidth = image.Width; for (x=0;x<imageWidth; x++) ...). Also, it's probably faster to sum up large ints and do a single division at the end instead of adding and dividing doubles. Also, if you want the last bit of performance, read about SIMD (https://instil.co/2016/03/21/parallelism-on-a-single-core-simd-with-c/) and other similar instruction sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Problem is that you let multiple tasks modify the same variable `parallelMean`. So you have a **Race Condition**.
I think also that the second result is not only false, it is also not stable: Mean try to execute the code again, and the second result will change
I think this code could solve your problem

```
double[] parallelMean = new double[image.Height];

Parallel.For(0, image.Height, i =>
{
    for (int j = 0; j < image.Width; j++)
        parallelMean[i] += (double)image[i, j] / totalPixels;
});

return parallelMean.Sum();
```

Comment: No overload for method 'For' takes 3 arguments

Comment: I am sorry I modified the code, I think it should works right now.

Comment: My solution is now similar to yours, with a small difference that I make the division at the end on the ´return parallelMean.Sum() / totalPixels´. This makes the iteration do only one operation and the division is only once, at the end, also the cast is not needed. The performance is similar between yours and this modification, taking in account several tests, but I opted for the division at the end.

Answer (score 5):

You are accessing a resource (the variable `parallelMean`) without synchronization from multiple threads. Some changes will overwrite each other, some reads will read wrong or old data. That's why you see a wrong result.

The simplest solution would be to put a `lock` statement around the write access to that variable, but that would force it back to doing it sequentially.

If you need to do computation on the results, it might be easier to use PLinq, that does large parts of the synchronization for you:

```
var mean = Enumerable.Range(0, image.Height)
                     .AsParallel()
                     .Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, image.Width)
                                            .AsParallel()
                                            .Sum(j => (double)image[i, j] / totalPixels))
                     .Sum();
```

Comment: I understand what you say, and this provides the correct result.. I'll measure the performance now, thanks

Comment: Be aware that AsParallel also adds some overhead and it's probably faster overall all to do it only on height.

Comment: After comparing times with a Stopwatch, I verified that @Andrew is right. This solution becomes slower than Hakam Fostok algorithm.

Comment: Parallelism is always a tradeoff. You need enough *to do* to make it worth spreading the work around. The smaller the picture, the larger the overhead compared to the actual work becomes.